# Magento 2 - Get all rates of customer

Tags: magento2, customer, ratings

How can I get all rates of the customer?

For review, I do it like this:

```
public function getReviews($isApproved=false)
{
    if($this->reviewData!=null)
        return $this->reviewData;
    $reviews=$this->reviewFactory->create();
    if ($isApproved) {
        $reviews->addFieldToFilter("approve_status",$this->status::Review_Approved);
    }
    $this->reviewData=$reviews;
    return $reviews;
}
```

Comment: for a particular customer?

Comment: any customer ... i wanna get list of rating by filtering customer id

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
$reviewFactory = $obj->get('\Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory')->create();

$reviews = $reviewFactory->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status_id', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('detail.customer_id', 2); //here add own customer ID
$reviews->getSelect()->joinInner(
            ['vote' => 'rating_option_vote'], 'main_table.review_id = vote.review_id'
        );
        //echo $reviews->getSelect()->__toString();exit;
foreach ($reviews as $key => $value) {
         print_r($value->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory as ReviewCollection;  // add it in constructor
// $value['entity_pk_value'] is the product id, u can use this to get product details

```
public function getRatingCollection(){

    $reviews = $this->collectionFactory
        ->addFieldToFilter('detail.customer_id', 44); //here add own customer ID
    $reviews->getSelect()->joinInner(
        ['vote' => 'rating_option_vote'], 'main_table.review_id = vote.review_id'
    );
    $reviews->getSelect()->joinInner(
        ['title' => 'rating'], 'vote.rating_id = title.rating_id'
    );

    echo "<pre/>";
    $reviewsData = $reviews->getData();
    //echo $reviews->getSelect()->__toString();exit;
    $allReview = [];
    $options = $this->getReviewStatuses();
    foreach ($reviewsData as $value) {
        $allReview[$value['review_id']]['created_at'] = $value['created_at'];
        $allReview[$value['review_id']]['title'] = $value['title'];
        $allReview[$value['review_id']]['detail'] = $value['detail'];
        $allReview[$value['review_id']]['nickname'] = $value['nickname'];
        $allReview[$value['review_id']]['status'] = $options[$value['status_id']];
        $allReview[$value['review_id']]['all_rating'][] = [
            $value['rating_code'] => $value['rating_code'],
            $value['percent'] => $value['percent']
            ]
        ;
    }

    var_dump($allReview);
}
public function getReviewStatuses()
{
    return [
        self::STATUS_APPROVED => 'Approved',
        self::STATUS_PENDING => 'Pending',
        self::STATUS_NOT_APPROVED => 'Not Approved'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-

```
protected $_reviewCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollection
){
    $this->_reviewCollection = $reviewCollection;
}

public function getReviewByCustomer($customerId)
{
    $collection = $this->_reviewCollection->create()
    ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->addCustomerFilter($customerId)
    ->setDateOrder()->addRateVotes();
    $collection->getData();

    foreach ($collection as $review) {
        print_r($review->getData());exit();
    }
}
```